# nil after converting string to date

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have really strage problem related with converting `String` to `Date` in `swift 3`

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
var maxDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: "1990-01-01 00:00:00")!
```

and it is ok. But when I am trying to do it like:

```
let dateTmp = day.doneDate
print (dateTmp!)
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateTmp!)
```

where value from `print(dateTmp)` is `2016-07-07 15:15:15` my `date` variable is `nil`

when I am trying to call:

```
var maxDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-07-07 15:15:15")!
```

`maxDate` variable is `nil`

when I print both values I strings in exactly same format:

```
2016-07-07 15:15:15
1990-01-01 00:00:00
```

can anyone give me a hint how to properly convert this string to `Date` ?

Comment: Your date is in 24 hours format so you need to use `HH` instead of `hh`, so simply change your dateFormat to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and you will able to get date object.

Comment: A tip, when you are almost done (like here), cut your string and your format into pieces until you find the culprit part of the format: "2016-07-07" with "yyyy-MM-dd" (should work for both examples) "00:00:00" with "hh:mm:ss" (won't for the for 15h), and so on, and then recheck the doc about the culprit part of the format.

Comment: @NiravD THANK YOU SO MUCH ! please copy your comment to answer so I will be able to mark it as done!